# Catch full URL in python

Tags: python, bottle

I'm developing application using Bottle. How do I get full query string when I get a GET Request.

I dont want to catch using individual parameters like:

```
param_a = request.GET.get("a","")
```

as I dont want to fix number of parameters in the URL.

How to get full query string of requested url

Comment: Using `GET` does not fix the number of parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the attribute [`request.query_string`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.query_string) to get the whole query string.

Comment: Ohhh yes. I tried it but I used like request.query_string() which was giving error. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`request.query`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.query) or `request.query.getall(key)` if you have more than one value for a single `key`.

For eg., `request.query.a` will return you the `param_a` you wanted. `request.query.b` will return the parameter for `b` and so on.

If you only want the query string alone, you can use @halex's answer.

Comment: Thanks. This too is useful for me.